# Hadoop: datanode process running but not working?

Tags: hadoop

We have been trying to install hadoop cluster these days. Sometimes succeed but most times failed. I make the configuration according to official document and some seems-high-quality blogs.

The problem I meet is:
All the process (including namenode,datanode, nodemanager,resourcemanager) can be seen by the command:`jps`

But the slaves are actually not working. I cannot see them in web interface master:8088 or master:50070

Someone said that is caused by repeated namenode format and the id conflict. I think that is not to my problem since the datanodes don't work from the very beginning and the datanode folder are always empty.

Is there any other possible causes to this phenomenon?
I am really suffering to setup the cluster.

Detail:

Hadoop version:3.0.0-alpha2

Output of hdfs dfsadmin -report is :

```
Configured Capacity: 492017770496 (458.23 GB)
Present Capacity: 461047037952 (429.38 GB)
DFS Remaining: 460770820096 (429.13 GB)
DFS Used: 276217856 (263.42 MB)
DFS Used%: 0.06%
Under replicated blocks: 10069
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0
Pending deletion blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Live datanodes (1):

Name: 127.0.0.1:9866 (localhost)
Hostname: sr145.local.lan
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 492017770496 (458.23 GB)
DFS Used: 276217856 (263.42 MB)
Non DFS Used: 5954019328 (5.55 GB)
DFS Remaining: 460770820096 (429.13 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.06%
DFS Remaining%: 93.65%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Sun Jan 02 02:52:57 CST 2000
```

**The only one live datanode is the same node of master node.**All the other slaves node are not live.

Configuration detail:
1,hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address</name>
        <value>sr145:9001</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>3</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:/opt/hadoop/hdfs/namenode</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>file:/opt/hadoop/hdfs/datanode</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

2,core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>file:/opt/hadoop/tmp</value>
        <description>Abasefor other temporary directories.</description>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

3,yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>

<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
        <property>
                <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
                <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.manager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
                <value>sr145</value>
        </property>
        <property>
           <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
           <value>sr145:8032</value>
        </property>
        <property>
           <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
           <value>sr145:8030</value>
        </property>
        <property>
           <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
           <value>sr145:8035</value>
        </property>
        <property>
           <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
           <value>sr145:8033</value>
        </property>
        <property>
           <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
           <value>sr145:8088</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

The configuration at all nodes are almost the same, only differs in the hdfs-site.xml natenode or datanode configuration. 
The `workers` and `slaves` files in $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop are also edited. No files are moved compared to the raw status.

Comment: You are able to see the datanode process with `jps` but not from the Web UI? Can you post the output of `hdfs dfsadmin -report` and also the configuration files to the question.

Comment: Thank you for concerning. I have pasted the details on this question. Please take a look...

Comment: When you start the DataNode service on one of the hosts, what do you see in the datanode log (default location = /var/log/hadoop-hdfs)?

Comment: Things come a little clear. The log for datanode is : 2017-04-20 08:28:34,133 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Problem connecting to server: sr145/10.0.0.45:9000  I try to ping the master form a slave. It works. Why can't make connection through hadoop?

Comment: the value of `fs.defaultFS` must be a valid hostname or an IP address for a multinode cluster setup. It should not be `localhost`

Comment: yes, that is the master node configuration ,my datanodes' are `hdfs://sr145:9000`. "sr145" is my master node, setted in `/etc/hosts` as `10.0.0.45       sr145
10.0.0.46       sr146
10.0.0.47       sr147
10.0.0.48       sr148
10.0.0.49       sr149
`

Comment: I'm getting the same problem. Any solution @AnyangWang??

Answer (score 2):

> The only one live datanode is the same node of master node.

Only that datanode is aware that namenode is bind to `localhost`, all the other datanodes are trying to connect with `sr145`.

The host value set in `fs.defaultFS` is where the Namenode daemon will be started. 
 Setting it to `localhost` in the master node made the process to bind to the loopback IP of the node. 
Edit the value to have the actual hostname or IP address, in this case it will be

```
<property>
   <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
   <value>hdfs://sr145:9000</value>
</property>
```

This property must be identical in all the nodes.

Comment: You are right. But it seems not my problem? The configuration I pasted above is for my master node. My slaves' setting is `hdfs://sr145:9000` like you said.

Comment: The configuration you have pasted has `localhost` set for defaultFS. That is wrong. Change it to the one as in the answer.